# How to display image in BIRT report using XML data source?

Tags: birt

I am using BIRT reporting tool version 2.5.2. I want to generate BIRT report in PDF format using XML data source. I have below XML node structure,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<columnDetails>
    <employeeDetails>
        <employeeName>{Name Of Employee}</employeeName>
        <employeeId>{Employee ID}</employeeId>
        <employeeSalary>{Employee Salary}</employeeSalary>
        <employeeImage>{Base64 encoded byte string of Employee Image}</employeeImage>
    </employeeDetails>
</columnDetails>
```

While generating the report, my XML data source is good enough to populate the employee details except the employee image. The generated PDF report displays “The resource of this item is not reachable” in place of the image.

My image item data set is properly mapped with “employeeImage” node of the data source XML and to render the image I have defined the source as dynamicImage with dynamicImage expression as

> “row[employeeImage]”

which is a Blob type data object.
Please suggest how I can fix this issue to display employee image in PDF report. Let me know incase you need any further clarification.

Answer (score -2):

The image can be added
a. As an embedded image. This however reduces reusability.
b. As part of a report library.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.